# "Failed to start Network Name Resolution/Time Synchronization"

Tags: boot, networking, kernel, 20.04, systemd

My Ubuntu 20 computer shut down when I wasn't looking, and now when I try tu turn it on the following messages appear over and over

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Starting Network Name Resolution...
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Starting Network Name Resolution...
```

The only difference between recovery and normal mode is that normal mode defaults to the black screen with circle animation and I need to press escape to see these messages. What do I do? I'd love to "See `'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service'`" but I don't even know how to enter a command, if I press ctrl+alt+fx (x!=1) I just get a black screen with a pulsating underscore where I can't do anything.

Update: I was able to turn it on after unplugging everything. So I change my question to "what happened and how can I prevent it in the future"

Comment: By unplugging it you mean you just rebooted? Having the same issue with a laptop and have taken the battery out and rebooted a few times unfortunately

Comment: @evan54 no, I unplugged every cable that was connected to the laptop (and then rebooted). It could've been a coincidence but I was rebooting it many times with no effect and after unplugging the cables it suddenly worked