# Ubuntu failed to boot and end up with splash screen

Tags: boot, login

I get to the Ubuntu log into screen enter my password and then it's stuck loading. Sometimes it doesn't get to the password screen and then if I hit escape j get the below screen shot. Any help appreciated

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Someone had a similar issue here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269495/failed-to-start-network-name-resolution-time-synchronization Their solution turned out to be unplugging everything and re plugging. Might be worth a try

Comment: So figured out a way to boot I ended up bioting from a previous kernel. Hopefully on the next update this'll get fixed

Comment: bioting = booting* typing from cell didn't help

Comment: A kernel update might not solve it. I’m guessing you have some device, possibly something to do with networking based on the error messages, that hasn’t had a module created for the newer kernel. Normally dkms would take care of it. This article might help https://www.xmodulo.com/build-kernel-module-dkms-linux.html